# Swift file in objc project can't be found while previously was there

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode

Not sure if this question is answered anywhere, I'm pretty sure I've seen answer long time ago but can't find it now.

This is variant of often asked problem "my objective-c code doesn't see Swift files" however with small twist. Previously everything was OK and those files were seen and project was compiling and running with some classes defined in obj-c and some in Swift. Now I'm getting error "PROJECTNAME-Swift.h file not found"

Any suggestion what could happened, how to restore this file if it was lost or how to force xCode to recreate it?

Answer (score 0):

OK - you can't loop this bridging. So if class Objc written in Objective-C is using class Swf written in Swift and class Swf is using Objc class then compiler is lost, probably because it can't generate any of those classes before the other is defined.